# How to save parsed and changed DOM document in xml file?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have xml-file. I need to read it, make some changes and write new changed version to some new destination.

I managed to read, parse and patch this file (with `DocumentBuilderFactory`, `DocumentBuilder`, `Document` and so on).

But I cannot find a way how to save that file. Is there a way to get it's plain text view (as `String`) or any better way?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult(new File("output.xml"));
Source input = new DOMSource(myDocument);

transformer.transform(input, output);
```

Comment: This will save to xml file in build project folder. But if I want to save it in the original xml file, then how should I do that? I try pasting original xml file Path but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

That will work, provided you're using [xerces-j](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/):

```
public void serialise(org.w3c.dom.Document document) {
  java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream data = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
  java.io.PrintStream ps = new java.io.PrintStream(data);

  org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat of =
                      new org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat("XML", "ISO-8859-1", true);
  of.setIndent(1);
  of.setIndenting(true);
  org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer serializer =
                      new org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer(ps, of);
  // As a DOM Serializer
  serializer.asDOMSerializer();
  serializer.serialize(document);

  return data.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will give you possibility to define xml format

```
new XMLWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName),
              new OutputFormat(){{
                        setEncoding("UTF-8");
                        setIndent("    ");
                        setTrimText(false);
                        setNewlines(true);
                        setPadText(true);
              }}).write(document);
```