# Modify an XML file with XPath in MATLAB

Tags: java, xml, matlab, xpath

I'm trying to open and modify an XML file in MATLAB using XPath. Here the code I have written so far:

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*
doc = xmlread(which('myXMLfile.xml'));

factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
xpath = factory.newXPath();
expr = xpath.compile('/data//parameter[@name=''MYPARAMETER'']/double');

nodeList = expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
disp(char(nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild.getNodeValue))

nodeList.item(0).setNodeValue('0.03')
```

And my XML file :

```
<data>
...
  <parameter name="MYPARAMETER">
    <double>0.05</double>
  </parameter>
...
```

The `disp` line correctly display in the MATLAB command window the value, which here is `0.05`.

The script doesn't throw an error. However, the `0.03` value is not set in the XML file. What am I doing wrong and why is the value not written to the file with the `setNodeValue` command?

**EDIT**

As proposed, it might not be saved because it is just modified in memory. I added the following lines to my code:

```
factory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformer = factory.newTransformer();

writer = java.io.StringWriter();
result = javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer);
source = javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(doc);

transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I'm getting no errors, but the XML file is still not modified.

**Edit 2**

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*
import javax.xml.transform.*
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

doc = xmlread(which('ImagingSensor.vpar'));

factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
xpath = factory.newXPath();
expr = xpath.compile('/data//parameter[@name=''FOV'']/double');

nodeList = expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
disp(char(nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild.getNodeValue))

nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild.setNodeValue('0.03')
```

With `nodeList.item(0).getFirstChild.setNodeValue('0.03')` the value is correctly changed (but still not saved to file).

When using `nodeList.item(0).setNodeValue('0.03')`, it didn't change the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're modifying only the XML document object in memory. Try to save the object back to XML file at the end. Something like this maybe* :

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult(new File("myXMLfile.xml"));
Source input = new DOMSource(myDocument);

transformer.transform(input, output);
```

*) I'm not a Java guy, snippet taken from this thread : [How to save parsed and changed DOM document in xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561734/how-to-save-parsed-and-changed-dom-document-in-xml-file)

Comment: If you print the node value after updating it, does it actually changed? looks like you're setting different node from the node you displayed before, no?

Comment: You are right. I printed the value after updating it and it was still the same. But even with this change, it is still not saved. See my second edit.

Comment: Just to make sure, does the 2nd edit followed by the 1st edit (saving back to file) when you tested?

Comment: Yes, my 2nd edit include the code from the 1st edit. Now, when I display the node value after changing it, I see that it is correctly changed.

Comment: your code using `java.io.StringWriter()`, but the thread I linked above use a `File()`. If I'm not mistaken, you need to save result of `writer.ToString()` to the XML file manually at the end then...