# remove a tag and alter a line in an XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

I have an XML in which I need to remove one whole tag from it using Java. As of now there is not specific position of that tag, it can be anywhere but it will be inside `client` tag.

```
<xml>

<client id="100" version="2">
    <!--  some stuff here -->

    <derta-config>
        <!--  some stuff here -->
    </derta-config>

    <!--  some stuff here -->

    <!--  some stuff here -->
</client>
```

I need to remove this `<derta-config>` tag altogether from the above XML. And there is one more thing. In the same XML file, I will have only once instance of this line `<hello>collect_model = 1</hello>`. Below `world` block can be anywhere and nested as well within various other `world` block. And it will be inside `client` tag as well but there might be other nesting as well.

```
<world>
    <world>
        <world>
            <world>
                <hello>collect_model = 1</hello>
                <hello>enable_data = 0</hello>
                <hello>session_ms = 1000</hello>
                <hello>max_collect = string_integer($extract("max_collect"))</hello>
                <hello>max_collect = parenting(max_collect, max_collect, 100)</hello>
                <hello>output('{')</hello>
            </world>
        </world>
    </world>
</world>
```

I need to make that line like this: `<hello>collect_model = 0</hello>` in the same `world` block. So my final XML will not have above `<derta-config>` tag and `collect_model` will be 0

```
<world>
    <world>
        <world>
            <world>
                <hello>collect_model = 0</hello>
                <hello>enable_data = 0</hello>
                <hello>session_ms = 1000</hello>
                <hello>max_collect = string_integer($extract("max_collect"))</hello>
                <hello>max_collect = parenting(max_collect, max_collect, 100)</hello>
                <hello>output('{')</hello>
            </world>
        </world>
    </world>
</world>
```

Below is my code and I am not sure what should I do to remove these things?

```
File fileName = new File("file example");
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(fileName);
```

**Update:-**

```
File fileName = new File("file example");
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(fileName);

NodeList configTag = document.getElementsByTagName("derta-config");
for (int i = 0; i < configTag.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = configTag.item(i);
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
    node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next you call [`document.getElementsByTagName("derta-config")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29), iterate the list (should be one long, right?), and use [`node.getParentNode().removeChild(node)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#removeChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29).

After that, you call `document.getElementsByTagName("hello")`, iterate the list, check the text content using [`node.getTextContent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29), and if it is the value you want to change, you change it with [`node.setTextContent(newValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent%28java.lang.String%29).

Then you save the result back to a file. See [How to save parsed and changed DOM document in xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561734/how-to-save-parsed-and-changed-dom-document-in-xml-file)

Comment: thanks Andreas, I got the idea but slightly confuse on second step, I have updated the question. Not sure what is `node` here.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this answer is great, OP clearly needs to be spoon-fed the entire solution. Have a +1 anyway, on me.

Comment: @david Look at the javadoc of [NodeList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html). Figure it out.

Comment: I did the same thing, I started iterating NodeList in a for loop but still confuse how are we deleting stuff.

Comment: @david Show what you did.

Comment: @david `NodeList` has **only 2 methods**. It's not that complex. Read the documentation!!!!

Comment: I think I got that working, see my update. That's what you meant?