# Insert tag into selected text of XML file in WebView in JavaFX8

Tags: xml, webview, javafx-8

From an XML file displayed in a WebView, I would like to be able to select text with the mouse, and when a button is pressed, add a unique XML tag to that selection.

Sample XML file fragment:

```
<p>
    some text that is in this paragraph
</p>
```

If I select "that is" from the above, and press the button, it should result in:

```
<p>
    some text <x id="foo">that is</x> in this paragraph
</p>
```

where `<x>` is a special tag I will use for my own purposes. It might have attributes, like an id or something.

I see that I can use bits of JS code to gather info about the HTML tags and locate the selected text in a given tag, but I don't know how to get an "absolute" location. Nor do I know how to inject the XML tag into the XML file. Or maybe I should treat it as an HTMLEditor or something? I just don't want the user to be able to change the XML file except in this particular way.

Any ideas? Very appreciated.

Comment: I found that I can use this `webEngine.executeScript("window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createElement(\"p\"))");`to add a paragraph, but it doesn't actually change the underlying file.

Answer (score 0):

The executed script is only changing the DOM as it exists in memory. You would need to use webEngine.getDocument() and then write that out over the underlying file. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561785/5284850) describes how that part of it is done.