# JGraphx how to export SVG file from graph

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx, jgraph

I'm using JGraphx, and I want to put export graph to an SVG file.
I tried
`Document document = (Document) mxCellRenderer.createSvgDocument(safetyTreeGraph, null, 1, Color.WHITE, null);`, but I don't know how to output that SVG document to local.  So What should I do next?

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561734/how-to-save-parsed-and-changed-dom-document-in-xml-file) will help you. Simply switch the extension to "svg" and write your `Document` into a file.

Comment: Great!!! It works!!! Thanks!!