# Can't save changes to XML file

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I'm creating a CRUD application. Just like in the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561734/how-to-save-parsed-and-changed-dom-document-in-xml-file), I am able to modify the XML document in memory, but I cannot persist changes to the XML file.

I'm already using the `.transform()` method as mentioned in the linked question.

Tiedosto.java contains methods to open the XML file and save changes:

```
package tuoterekisteri;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Tiedosto implements Serializable {

    // luokan muuttujat
    protected DocumentBuilderFactory tehdas = null;
    protected DocumentBuilder rakentaja = null;
    protected Document dokumentti = null;
    protected URL polku = null;
    protected File tiedosto = null;
    protected DOMSource lahde = null;
    protected TransformerFactory muuntajatehdas = null;
    protected Transformer muuntaja = null;
    protected StreamResult tulos = null;
    protected StreamResult konsolitulos = null;

    public Document getDokumentti() {
        return this.dokumentti;
    }

    public boolean haeTuoterekisteri() {
        boolean ok = true;
        try {
            polku = Tuoterekisteri.class.getResource("tuotteet.xml");
            tiedosto = new File(polku.getFile());
            tehdas = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            rakentaja = tehdas.newDocumentBuilder();
            dokumentti = rakentaja.parse(this.tiedosto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    public boolean tallennaMuutokset() {
        boolean ok = true;
        try {
            muuntajatehdas = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            muuntaja = muuntajatehdas.newTransformer();            
            lahde = new DOMSource(dokumentti);
            tulos = new StreamResult(this.tiedosto);
            muuntaja.transform(lahde, tulos);

            // tulostus
            konsolitulos = new StreamResult(System.out);
            muuntaja.transform(lahde, konsolitulos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

}
```

Tuoterekisteri.java contains a method to add a new node to the document:

```
package tuoterekisteri;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tuoterekisteri extends Tiedosto {

    // luokan muuttujat
    int poistettavaid = 0;
    int haettavaid = 0;
    ArrayList<String> tiedot = new ArrayList<String>();
    int poistettavaindeksi = 0;

    public void lisaaTuote(String nimi, int hinta) {
        try {
            Element juuri = dokumentti.getDocumentElement();
            Element uusituote = dokumentti.createElement("tuote");

            Element eid = dokumentti.createElement("id");
            eid.appendChild(dokumentti.createTextNode(String.valueOf(luoId())));
            uusituote.appendChild(eid);

            Element enimi = dokumentti.createElement("nimi");
            enimi.appendChild(dokumentti.createTextNode(nimi));
            uusituote.appendChild(enimi);

            Element ehinta = dokumentti.createElement("hinta");
            ehinta.appendChild(dokumentti.createTextNode(String.valueOf(hinta)));
            uusituote.appendChild(ehinta);

            juuri.appendChild(uusituote);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public int luoId() {
        String id = "0";
        NodeList tuotteet = this.dokumentti.getElementsByTagName("tuote");
        for (int i = 0; i < tuotteet.getLength(); i++) {
            Element tuote = (Element) tuotteet.item(i);
            NodeList idt = tuote.getElementsByTagName("id");
            id = idt.item(0).getTextContent();
        }
        int id2 = Integer.parseInt(id);
        int luku = (id2 >= 0) ? (id2 += 1) : (id2 = 1);
        return id2;
    }

}
```

lisaa.jsp calls the `haeTuoterekisteri()` method which opens the document and then calls the `lisaaTuote()` method which adds the new node. Finally `tallennaMuutokset()` method is called which should save the changes to the file itself. Here is the problem: no error is thrown and neither are the changes saved to the XML file.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean class="tuoterekisteri.Tuoterekisteri" id="tuoterekisteri"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>XML-tuoterekisteri</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Lisää tuote</h1>

        <form method="post">
            Nimi: <input type="text" name="nimi"><br>
            Hinta: <input type="number" name="hinta"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="nappi">
            <input type="submit" name="peruuta" value="Peruuta">
        </form>

        <%

            if (tuoterekisteri.haeTuoterekisteri() && request.getParameter("nappi") != null) {
                    String nimi = request.getParameter("nimi");
                    int hinta = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("hinta"));

                    tuoterekisteri.lisaaTuote(nimi, hinta);
                    if (tuoterekisteri.tallennaMuutokset() == true) {
                        System.out.println("lisäys ok");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("lisäys epäonnistui");
                    }
            }

            if (request.getParameter("peruuta") != null) {
                response.sendRedirect("/tuoterekisteri");
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Original tuotteet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tuotteet>
    <tuote xml:id="1">
        <id>1</id>
        <nimi>Lapio</nimi>
        <hinta>5</hinta>
    </tuote>
    <tuote xml:id="2">
        <id>2</id>
        <nimi>Kirves</nimi>
        <hinta>10</hinta>
    </tuote>
    <tuote xml:id="3">
        <id>3</id>
        <nimi>Vasara</nimi>
        <hinta>15</hinta>
    </tuote>
    <tuote xml:id="5">
            <id>5</id>
            <nimi>Porakone</nimi>
            <hinta>20</hinta>
    </tuote>
</tuotteet>
```

StreamResult(System.out):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><tuotteet>
    <tuote xml:id="1">
        <id>1</id>
        <nimi>Lapio</nimi>
        <hinta>5</hinta>
    </tuote>
    <tuote xml:id="2">
        <id>2</id>
        <nimi>Kirves</nimi>
        <hinta>10</hinta>
    </tuote>
    <tuote xml:id="3">
        <id>3</id>
        <nimi>Vasara</nimi>
        <hinta>15</hinta>
    </tuote>
    <tuote xml:id="5">
            <id>5</id>
            <nimi>Porakone</nimi>
            <hinta>20</hinta>
    </tuote>
<tuote><id>6</id><nimi>asd</nimi><hinta>123</hinta></tuote><tuote><id>7</id><nimi>asd</nimi><hinta>123</hinta></tuote></tuotteet>lisäys ok
```

Comment: "contains methods to open the XML file and save changes" - no, it doesn't. Nothing is saved. Where is the part where you write to the file?

Comment: @f1sh tallennaMuutokset() method in the same file.

Comment: i am aware of that. But that method does not save anything to a file.

Comment: Can you then tell me how to save the changes to a file.

Comment: I do not see any code to save document to a file... Do you see modified output in `System.out` after those lines `konsolitulos = new StreamResult(System.out); muuntaja.transform(lahde, konsolitulos);`?

Comment: I added the original XML file structure and the output of the program.